# Is limit can be calculated term by term for finite sum?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Find the limit of the function:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_1 ^n (\pi /n)\sin( i\pi/n)$$

By calculating individually term by term each limit is $0$ so the sum should be $0$. But I am not very much sure whether the answer is correct or not.

Comment: The number of terms in the sum grows unbounded, thus you cannot simply take the termwise limit. Consider $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n}$. Do you recognise a Riemann sum in your limit?

Comment: Yep...Got it, But what is the answer for this question?

Comment: Do you see a Riemann sum?

Comment: Answer is $\ing$ $\pi sin(\pi x)dx$ limit is 0 to 1?

Comment: Answer is $2$...

Comment: Ah, now you edited the missing $\pi$ in. Then it's correct. Also, $\int_0^\pi \sin x\,dx$.

Comment: You are using the letter $n$ as the upper bound of summation, so that, for example, if $n=3$, then it's $\sum_1^3$.  If it were $\sum_{k=1}^3 k^5$ then it would be $1^5+2^5+3^5$, but you have something like $n^5$ instead of $k^5$, so it's $3^5+3^5+3^5$.  In other words,  don't use the SAME letter as the index of summation that you're using as the bound, unless you really intend every term in the sum to be the same,  with the index equal to the upper bound of summation.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The summation index here is most likely $i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer : If so, then writing $\sum_{i=1}^n$ would certainly have made that crystal-clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a Riemann sum and its limit is $\pi \int_{0}^{1} \sin(\pi x) dx$.